# How to change Django's start server time format?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-timezone

When I start django server using following command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It shows current time likes:

```
 January 02, 2018 - 15:35:17
```

But I want to see time format:

```
January 02, 2018 - 3:35:17pm
```

How can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why would some pretty much meaningless date and time and its format in the printout when you run development server be an issue. You cannot change that without changing source code. It's hardcoded. See source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution that i found for doing this site wide would be to setting in your settings.py the following global variable:

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p',]
```

I hope this helps someone.

To use other formats see:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: This is not relevant and doesn't answer the question.